# How can I change the line endings used by fputcsv?

Tags: php, csv, line-endings

I create a CSV file for download by our client using

```
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
```

and using `fputcsv()` to write data to a CSV file which is downloaded by the client.

I am running PHP on Linux and consequently the line endings are not interpreted by many Windows applications.

I could write the CSV file to a directory on the server, read it back in and perform a `str_replace()` from `\n` to `\r\n`, but this seems a rather clunky way of solving the problem. Is there a way to perform the conversion without creating a physical file?

Comment: Unless the user is opening the file in a Windows text editor that requires CRLF, or some pretty old Windows apps, then it shouldn't actually matter... most Windows applications these days do recognise a simple LF instead

Comment: Sorry for +1 you were at 1337, the most graceful rep. But your question interests me, no way to change escape char too...

Comment: @MarkBaker: Yes, that's what I expected. Unfortunately, they're importing the CSV into some MIS they use, which doesn't appear to be any smarter than Notepad in this regard.

Comment: Have you read the comments in the manual for fputcsv? http://lv.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php#90883

Comment: @lix: Yes, I certainly have, and I could fall back on the specific function you linked to, but I wanted to use `fputcsv()` and just convert the line endings afterwards, rather than replicating the entire functionality of `fputcsv()` and adding the line ending conversion. The PHP user notes aren't always the best resource. That's why I come here :)

Comment: You can find a brilliant and short solutions here:
[Setting Custom Line Endings in fputcsv()](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7961173/2931427)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could use stream filters to accomplish this. This example writes to a physical file, but it should work fine for `php://output` as well.

```
// filter class that applies CRLF line endings
class crlf_filter extends php_user_filter
{
    function filter($in, $out, &$consumed, $closing)
    {
        while ($bucket = stream_bucket_make_writeable($in)) {
            // make sure the line endings aren't already CRLF
            $bucket->data = preg_replace("/(?<!\r)\n/", "\r\n", $bucket->data);
            $consumed += $bucket->datalen;
            stream_bucket_append($out, $bucket);
        }
        return PSFS_PASS_ON;
    }
}
// register the filter
stream_filter_register('crlf', 'crlf_filter');

$f = fopen('test.csv', 'wt');
// attach filter to output file
stream_filter_append($f, 'crlf');
// start writing
fputcsv($f, array('1 1', '2 2'));
fclose($f);
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you can do this with PHP itself.  There may be a way to change PHP's EOL for file writing, but it's probably system dependent.  You don't have a windows system you could ping, do you? ;)

As for a real solution, instead of `str_replace` line-by-line, you could use the Linux program `unix2dos` (inverse of `dos2unix`) assuming you have it installed:

```
fputcsv($fh ...)
exec("unix2dos " . escapeshellarg($filename));
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Create the file with \n line endings on a Linux machine
2. FTP the file as ASCII from the Linux machine to a Windows machine
3. Hey presto! All line endings are now \r\n in the file on the Windows machine

Answer (score 1):

Rather than writing the file, a better solution is to use output buffering

```
function output($buffer) {
    return str_replace("\n", "\r\n", $buffer);
} 

ob_start('output');
fputcsv(....);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since PHP 8.1 [fputcsv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) accepts a new `$eol` parameter to do this. By default is "\n" but can change it to "\r\n".

```
fputcsv($stream, $fields, eol: "\r\n");
```

Answer (score -1):

If PHP is not properly recognizing the line endings when reading files either on or created by a Macintosh computer, enabling the auto_detect_line_endings run-time configuration option may help resolve the problem.
ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", true);

Comment: It is working in my case when csv file generated from Mac device not parsing.