# Force new line in CSV generated file in PHP

Tags: php, file-io, download, fputcsv

I am generating a CSV downloadable file in PHP. I have a problem that when I open file in MS Excell or Ubuntu Libre Office the formate is not like what is expected.

I want this output but I can not force to start from new line.

```
Name           Slope   Length   Size(Inches)      Max Length         Location                                       
Name1            5      150       12"                500            location1   
Name2            8      350       12"                400            location 2  
Name3           16      326       12"                400            location3
```

This is my PHP code

```
        $csv_data[] = $_POST['name'][$i];
        $csv_data[] = $_POST['slope'][$i];
        $csv_data[] = $_POST['length'][$i];
        $csv_data[] = $size;
        $csv_data[] = $max_length;
        $csv_data[] = $_POST['location'][$i].PHP_EOLE;


    header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv');

    $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    fputcsv($output, array("Name", "Slope", "Length", "Size", "Max Length", "Location"));
    fputcsv($output, $csv_data);
```

But this code output like this:

```
Name    Slope   Length  Size    Max Slope Length    Location                                                
Name1   5   150 12" 500 location1   Name2   8   350 12" 400 location 2  Name3   16  326 12" 400 location3
```

Comment: Look at the file in an editor that can read Unix or Windows newlines correctly

Comment: I read this output in MS WordPad and the output was nearly as expected but I need it also to be readable in MS Excell.

Comment: Try reading the output in notepad.exe **not wordpad**. Please post your full code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I change the line endings used by fputcsv?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12722894/how-can-i-change-the-line-endings-used-by-fputcsv)

Comment: MS Excel doesn't care whether it's \n\r, \r\n or simply \n, it should work with them all... WordPad !== MSExcel

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im: Now I paste here full code, and the output is also shown on one line in Notepad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did is I make the `$csv_data` array two dimensional instead of one and then I use `foreach` loop. Its a bit slow but working for me.

Here is the updated code

```
    $csv_data[$i][] = $_POST['name'][$i];
    $csv_data[$i][] = $_POST['slope'][$i];
    $csv_data[$i][] = $_POST['length'][$i];
    $csv_data[$i][] = $size;
    $csv_data[$i][] = $max_length;
    $csv_data[$i][] = $_POST['location'][$i];

    header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv');

    $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    fputcsv($output, array("Name", "Slope", "Length", "Size", "Max Length", "Location"));
    foreach ($csv_data as $value) {
        fputcsv($output, $value);
    }
```

This is the output which I was need.

```
Name    Slope   Length  Size    Max Length  Location
Name1    5       150    12"        500      location1 
Name2    8       350    12"        400      location12
Name3    16      326    12"        400      location3 
Name4    36      127    12"        400      location4
```

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

```
$csv_headers = array(array("Name", "Slope", "Length", "Size", "Max Length", "Location"));
$csv_full_data = array_merge($csv_headers, $csv_data);
var_dump($csv_full_data);
fputcsv($output, $csv_full_data);
```

And tell us the output.

Comment: I try doing this your way and this is the output, its still on one line

Array Name1 5 150 12" 500 location1  Name2 8 350 12" 400 location12 Name3 16 326 12" 400 location3  Name4 36 127 12" 400 location4

Comment: Thanks it did not work for me, but it give me an idea, I solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

what is the value of PHP_EOL make it "\r\n" and try

```
$csv_data[] = $_POST['location'][$i].PHP_EOL; change to 
$csv_data[] = $_POST['location'][$i]."\r\n";
```