# PHP fputcsv insert into a new line in csv file

Tags: php, csv, fputcsv

I have a file name **checklist.csv**

I try to insert a new information in this file using `php`

My method work and i can insert a new information in the file

But i have a problem that the new information is near the past information

**Example**

,92,electrical,Final As built drawing,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,93,electrical,test,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

**But what i want is to look like this in the file:**

,92,electrical,Final As built drawing,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

,93,electrical,test,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

This is the code i use

```
 $number=secure($_POST['txt_number'],"num");
      $category=secure($_POST['txt_category'],"text");
      $desc=secure($_POST['txt_desc'],"ibtext");
      $file = fopen('checklist.csv', 'a+');
      $csv=array();
      $csv[]="";
      $csv[]=$number;
      $csv[]=$category;
      $csv[]=$desc;
      $csv[]="";
      $csv[]="";
      $csv[]="";
      $csv[]="";
      $csv[]="";
      $csv[]="";
      $csv[]="";
      $csv[]="";
      $csv[]="";
      $csv[]="";
      $csv[]="";
      $csv[]="";
      $csv[]="";
      $csv[]="";
      $csv[]="";
      $csv[]="";
      $csv[]="";
      $csv[]="";
      $csv[]="";
      $csv[]="";
      fputcsv($file,$csv);
      fclose($file);
```

How I add the new information in a new line??!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I expect that you are opening the CSV file on Windows.

Windows only shows a new line for `\r\n` whereas Linux shows a new line for `\n`.

See [fputcsv and newline codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080456/fputcsv-and-newline-codes) for someone else who has had a similar issue.