# Line-Breaks on PHP fputcsv

Tags: php, csv, line-breaks, fputcsv

I have this code.

```
$value1 = '1';
$value2 = '2';
$value3 = '3';

$field = array ("field1", "field2", "field3");
$value = array ($value1, $value2, $value3);

$list = array ($field, $value);

$fp = fopen ('file.csv', 'w');

foreach ($list as $fields) {
   fputcsv ($fp, $fields);
}

fclose ($fp);
```

But the result is like this:

```
field1,field2,field3,1,2,3
```

And I want a line-break on the CSV, like this:

```
field1,field2,field3
1,2,3
```

And without doble-quotes, as showed.

Any sugestion? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fputcsv and newline codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080456/fputcsv-and-newline-codes)

Comment: _But the result is like this_ What result?  How are you viewing it?

Comment: Tested but it doesn't worked for me. I'm not use a function.

Comment: @abracadaver in the generated csv :S

Comment: No, how do you VIEW the CSV?  The linebreak IS in the CSV, what you are using to view it just doesn't show it.

Comment: When you say the result is like this: `field1,field2,field3,1,2,3` ... is that an 'actual' copy/paste here? Or did you type it here in stackoverflow. Because that extra comma in there after field3 before 1 is questionable. And there are no "double-quotes as showed" here.

Comment: No. On my generated csv the line is not broken. All is in a single line with the Default Notepad.

Comment: Because notepad doesn't render newlines, it needs _carriage return_ and _newline_. `\r\n`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran the code and the result is exactly what you want.
Which is:

```
field1,field2,field3
1,2,3
```

There is a line break (0x0A) after "field3" and another line break after "3".
IncredibleHat is correct, there is absolutely no comma after "field3".

See the output at http://codepad.org/k6d0t8nU

Answer (score 0):

Based on your answers I downloaded other text editor most advanced and I can see the line-break.

For any reason, Notepad is not showing correct.